# Keep multiple copies of file from being opened in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, file-locking

I have a WPF app, which opens and edits XML files. Currently, the app can be launched multiple times, and several instances can have the same file open. I need to lock the files such that, when one is open, it won't let another instance of the app open the file. I have tried using the FileShare.None attribute when opening the file, as well as FileStream.Lock(), but for some reason, these fail to prevent a separate instance of the app from opening it.

EDIT: Relevant code

```
try
{
    FileStream iStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    iStream.Lock(0, iStream.Length);

    // DO STUFF WITH FILE HERE
}
catch (System.IO.IOException ioException)
{
    // Raise exception to higher level, where application will terminate. 
    throw (ioException);
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code, it will make it much easier to get help.

Comment: Setting `FileShare.None` should be enough.  You don't need the call to `Lock()`.  Can you post a smaller, more complete example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep file open all the time you are "editing" it from the moment you start editing till closing (assuming you have separate processes for each instance of your app).

Your code looks like you are opening file inside on method and likely close it inside this method either by using "using" as recommended for short file operations or just letting GC to close it. As result you lock file for some time, but release it soon enough for other instances to be able to open it again.

Note that if your application implements some sort of single instance approach this locking may not be enough as all of the open operations will be executed from the same process.

Comment: I know for a fact I am not explicitly closing the file. However, as you said, it could be the GC closing it for me. How would I go about preventing the GC from closing it?

Comment: Nevermind. I moved the scope of the FileStream object into my object, instead of just declaring it in the method.